# Constraint for a unique column if other column has same value

Tags: mysql, group-by, unique-constraint

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a column be unique for each value of another column in MySQL. What I'm wanting to have is the same functionality as what a `GROUP BY` would do.

Here's the table:

```
CREATE TABLE Example (
    id INT,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

The data would be similar to this:

```
INSERT INTO Example (id, name) VALUES(1, 'Peter Parker');
```

The following would work:

```
INSERT INTO Example (id, name) VALUES(1, 'Bruce Wayne');
INSERT INTO Example (id, name) VALUES(2, 'Peter Parker');
```

The following would not work (as there's the same name with that id):

```
INSERT INTO Example (id, name) VALUES(1, 'Peter Parker');
```

Hopefully this can help clear things up for what I want:

- There can be multiple rows with the same ID
- There can be multiple rows with the same name
- There cannot be multiple rows with the same ID **and** name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, what you want is something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Example (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY uix_name_example (name)
);
```

The `id` field is the `PRIMARY KEY` and its value is taken care of by the server. A `UNIQUE KEY` on `name` ensures no duplicates are allowed - and `NOT NULL` ensures (hopefully) meaningful values.

```
INSERT INTO Example (name) VALUES ('Peter Parker'); -- specify name, but not id - it's automatic
INSERT INTO Example (name) VALUES ('Billy Joe McAlister');
INSERT INTO Example (name) VALUES ('Bill Clinton');
```

Check your table:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM Example;
+----+---------------------+
| id | name                |
+----+---------------------+
|  3 | Bill Clinton        |
|  2 | Billy Joe McAlister |
|  1 | Peter Parker        |
+----+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

A subsequent attempt to `INSERT` the same name (Peter Parker) fails.

```
mysql> INSERT INTO Example (name) VALUES('Peter Parker');
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'Peter Parker' for key 'uix_name_example'
mysql>
```

If you want to allow people with the same name, but different ids, then you just leave out the `UNIQUE KEY uix_name_example (name)` line in the table definition.

```
mysql> INSERT INTO Example VALUES(1, 'Peter Parker');
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
mysql>
```

If this isn't a satisfactory explanation, please expand your question.

---

**(EDIT in response to OP's comment and clarification)**

What you want is a `UNIQUE KEY` (or `INDEX`) on the combined id and name fields - also known as a composite index (or key). The syntax for this is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Example2 (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY uix_example (id, name)
);
```

Duplicate ids with different names allowed to be inserted.

```
mysql> INSERT INTO Example2 VALUES(1, 'Peter Parker');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.12 sec)
mysql> INSERT INTO Example2 VALUES(1, 'Billy Power');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.08 sec)
```

Same name allowed to be inserted with different ids

```
mysql> INSERT INTO Example2 VALUES(1, 'Mary Hanlon');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO Example2 VALUES(2, 'Mary Hanlon');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)
```

But, what is **not** allowed is to insert same id **and** same name.

```
mysql> INSERT INTO Example2 VALUES(1, 'Peter Parker');
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1-Peter Parker' for key 'uix_example'
mysql>
```

Hopefully this resolves your question.

Comment: No, that's not what I want. I added points to explain the rules I want in the question above.

Comment: Check out my edit where I added supplementary information about composite `UNIQUE INDEX`es (or `KEY`s).