# Having primary key in both fields but repeated in either fields allowed repeating

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

Is it possible to have both fields to be primary key but allows repeating  For either 1 field in Oracle SQL.

```
   Student_ID  Date
   1001        23/10/2016  // allowed
   1002        23/10/2016  // allowed
   1002        24/10/2016  // allowed
   1002        24/10/2016  // not allowed
```

Comment: I don't have an Oracle to test on.  A composite key.  But Date in Oracle includes a time component so you could have a date with multiple times.  Use triggers to remove the time time :new.yourdatecolumn := trunc(:new.yourdatecolumn);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same goal by having a `UNIQUE` composite index on the desired fields.

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
  add CONSTRAINT YourTable_unique UNIQUE (A, B,....);
```

(`A`, `B`,...) - fields `A`, `B`,... should be declared as `NOT NULL`.

This might be helpful if you have a surrogate `PRIMARY KEY` which you may want to keep. Something similar was recently asked for MySQL [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135544/constraint-for-a-unique-column-if-other-column-has-same-value), but the principle is the same.

You can also perform the same operation during the [`CREATE TABLE`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/unique.php) statement:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
  column1 datatype NOT NULL,
  column2 datatype NOT NULL,
  ...

  CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE (uc_col1, uc_col2, ... uc_col_n)
);
```